# Use of both double and single quotes in a bash script for calling a program

Tags: bash, shell, command-line

I have a bash script that takes a couple of arguments. This script does some work and then opens another program using these two arguments.
To open that program, the command requires the use of both single and double quotes, like this:

```
myprogram -a value1 -b 'Main("value2")'
```

But I can't figure how to do this in bash.

When I just put this into my script:

```
myprogram -a $1 -b 'Main("$2")'
```

The $2 variable is not expanded.

Any clue of how to achieve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to your program should look like this:

```
myprogram -a "$1" -b "Main(\"$2\")"
```

or

```
myprogram -a "$1" -b 'Main("'"$2"'")'
```

In both of these examples, the two positional parameters `$1` and `$2` are protected from the shell by double quotes.  This means that the shell will not split their values on white spaces and will not perform filename globbing on their values (in case they contain filename globbing characters), but the shell will still *expand* them (in your example, the single quotes around `$2` prevents the shell from even seeing `$2`).

`'Main("'"$2"'")'` is the concatenation of three strings:  `Main("`, the quoted value of `$2`, and `")`, while `"Main(\"$2\")"` is just a single double quoted string with a couple of escaped double quotes.